# Angular UI Modal moves the page when is open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

In angular ui, even in the source page example when you open the modal the page behind is moved about 5 px more or less.

Open the modal in the page and look at how the page is moved.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

[image]

Somebody knows why or how to workaround this issue. I tested in two of my monitors. It is the best angular modal or there's other better modals?

Comment: use this one https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.dialog

Comment: I didnt see such moving. Anyway, 'modal' - is just several divs u can manage their styles as u wish.

Comment: I try it in three different computers and the behavior it's the same. Can't you see that the page behind the modal moves when the modal is opened?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a common issue so investigating some I found this answer, It worked for me:

```
/* This prevent Content moves to the right*/
 body.modal-open { 
   overflow:inherit; 
  padding-right:inherit !important; 
 }
```

To see other answers go the following link:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9886